# Race condition of buffered C++ streams when calling fork -- force flush?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file-io, fork, flush

I have a program that spawns a writer thread with UNIX `fork()`. This works fine, but when a buffered C++ stream has not been flushed yet, I get a race condition where two threads output the same data. The following example shows what I mean:

```
extern "C" {
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
}

#define W 10

#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
   pid_t pid;
   int status;
   for (int i = 0; i < (1 << W); i++) {

      // spawn a child after adding to the std::cout buffer
      if (i == (1 << (W - 1))) {
         // std::cout.flush(); // (1)
         pid = fork();
         if (!pid)
            break;
      }

      // join the child thread after a while
      if (i == 3 * (1 << (W - 2)))
         waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

      // print stuff to the stream
      std::cout << i << '\n';
      // std::cout << i << std::endl; // (2)
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So the workaround I tried are to (1) flush `std::cout` by hand right before calling `fork()` (preferred solution), or (2) using `std::endl` when writing to the stream, but this adds unnecessarily many `flush` calls. Although this kind of works for `std::cout` which is globally accessible, my preferred solution (1) does not work for other buffered streams that are *not* globally accessible. Besides, at some point I might open another file and I would probably forget to flush it then.

Is there a better solution to this problem? Like a function that **flushes all** buffered **C++ streams**?

---

**EDIT**

A suggested solution was to use `fflush(nullptr)` from the C library to flush all (C) streams. This works for `std::cout` and `std::cerr` which are kept in sync with `stdout` and `stderr`, but other C++ buffered streams will **not** be synced. This demonstrates the problem:

```
extern "C" {
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
}

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define W 10

int main(void)
{
   pid_t pid;
   int status;
   std::ofstream fout("foo");

   for (int i = 0; i < (1 << W); i++) {

      if (i == (1 << (W - 1))) {
         fflush(nullptr);  // this works for std::{cout,cerr} but not files
         pid = fork();
         if (!pid)
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }

      if (i == 3 * (1 << (W - 2)))
         waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

      fout << i << '\n';
      std::cout << i << '\n';
   }
   fout.close();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my system I get

```
$ ./a.out 1>bar; wc -l foo bar
1536 foo
1024 bar
```

Needless to say that the number of lines should be equal.

Any further ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`fflush`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush), and pass it `nullptr`.

From the man:

```
#include <cstdio> // adapted the include for C++

int fflush(FILE *stream);
```

> If the stream argument is NULL, fflush() flushes all open output streams.

Comment: well.. aren't c++ buffered streams and C buffered streams two different things? Then the C function would most likely only flush the C streams.

Comment: I think that as long as `sync_with_stdio(true);` for the standard streams, then you're ok (since they will use the same buffers). But I don't think the other opened streams will be flushed though.